# Getting div containers to display hidden and then show with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an admin panel and I have a panel on the left side of my page that I want to bring up different data.

I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekrosn6a/) to show what I am doing.

The issue I am having is I want the dashboard home message...

```
<div id="dashboard_home">Welcome to the Admin Dashboard</div>
```

To be the only div that shows up on page load. Then when a panel seletion is clicked on, for the dashboard home message to go away and then only that new panel selection's div to show up.

Then once another panel selection is clicked on, I want the previous selection to hide and the new one to display and so fourth for all of the selections.

What do I need to do?

HTML

```
<div class="panel_out">
    <div class="panel">
        <input type='button' class="panel_buttons" id='user_request_button' value='User Requests'>
        <input type='button' class="panel_buttons" id='message_button' value='Message Center'>
        <input type='button' class="panel_buttons" id='draft_order_button' value='Draft Order'>
        <input type='button' class="panel_buttons" id='draft_input_button' value='Draft Input'>
        <input type='button' class="panel_buttons" id='announcements_button' value='Announcements'>
        <input type='button' class="panel_buttons" id='dues_button' value='League Dues'>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="dashboard_selection">
    <div id='user_requests'>User Requests</div>
    <div id='message_center'>Message Center</div>
    <div id='draft_order'>Draft Order</div>
    <div id='draft_input'>Draft Input</div>
    <div id='announcements'>Announcements</div>
    <div id='dues'>Leauge Dues</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#user_request_button').on('click', function (event) {
        jQuery('#user_requests').toggle('hide');
    });
    jQuery('#message_button').on('click', function (event) {
        jQuery('#message_center').toggle('hide');
    });
    jQuery('#draft_order_button').on('click', function (event) {
        jQuery('#draft_order').toggle('hide');
    });
    jQuery('#draft_input_button').on('click', function (event) {
        jQuery('#draft_input').toggle('show');
    });
    jQuery('#announcements_button').on('click', function (event) {
        jQuery('#announcements').toggle('show');
    });
    jQuery('#dues_button').on('click', function (event) {
        jQuery('#dues').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you asking for?

Comment: I don't want any of the div's to show up until they are clicked on and then when one is active, if another one is clicked on, I want the previous one to go away.

Comment: Ok but at a time one must show right? Means never all of them goes away right?

Comment: You should consider using Bootstrap for your CSS and `.hidden`

Comment: @vogomatix Why is that?

Comment: @vogomatix can you explain how that would help at all?

Comment: Because you can change your styling to hide divs initially and then remove the .hidden class on click

Comment: @vogomatix and why would you need all of bootstrap for that one CSS rule?

Comment: You don't need all of Bootstrap - but it's not very big anyway and saves reinventing the wheel

Comment: @vogomatix `.hidden{display: none;}` is hardly a reinvention of a wheel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ekrosn6a/7/)**

You're adding far too many bespoke events when you don't need to. Normalise your IDs to match the button IDs and derive one from the other,

e.g. `<input id='user_requests_button' />` finds `<div id="user_requests">`

Show the div you want, then use `siblings()` to get the elements that you want hidden, and hide them.

Trigger the click event on the first button on load to show the first one only when the page loads (if you don't do this with CSS).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('.panel_out input').on('click', function(){
        // derive the ID
        var id_to_show = '#' + this.id.replace('_button', '');
        // show one and hide the others
        $(id_to_show).show().siblings().hide();
    }).first().trigger('click'); // trigger the first on page load
});
```

Trigger the click event on the first button on load to show the first one only when the page loads (if you don't do this with CSS).

Comment: How can I have this show first and then allow me to click the buttons? to show them.. `<div id="dashboard_welcome">Welcome to the Admin Dashboard</div>` Here is what I mean. https://jsfiddle.net/ekrosn6a/4/

Comment: There is no Welcome to the Admin Dashboard in the code.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot I couldn't save yours.. Here you are... https://jsfiddle.net/2g1t0krs/

Comment: You would simply add `$('#dashboard_welcome').hide();` within the click function. You already know how to hide elements.

Comment: How doesn't it? `<div class="dashboard_selection">
    <div id="dashboard_welcome">Welcome to the Admin Dashboard</div>`

Comment: In the HTML in the Jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes, the new one I added. 3rd comment down.

Comment: So don't use `.first().trigger('click')` and just hide the ones you dont' want on page load with CSS, which is all but the first

Answer (score 1):

On a click hide all panels first. And then open the desired one with .show()

So i would do it this way:

```
$('.panel').click(function(e){
 $('.panel').hide();
 $(e.currentTarget).closest('panel').show();
});
```